# NSURLSession HTTP client not returning request in correct order

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, nsurlsession

I've written a plugin to perform GET/POST calls. 
Most the calls works except when I have multiple calls :P.

Debugging in XCode I can see that the data (response) from the calls are there however not in the order that I am expecting. 
How can I make sure that the response are in the correct order?

Example of the error: I place 3 calls, in my JS code I'm receiving the response of call02 instead of call01.

My code for reference:
http://pastebin.com/npgNn2Jk

Comment: Don't make the second until the first one finish. But if you receive the response of 2 on call 1 then your plugin is wrong, that shouldn't happen, you should store the requests on an array and check which request returned which response

Comment: Actually I was passing a global callbackID and it works for single calls but once I had multiples calls the same global callbackID was being passed to the handler resulting in a wrong response lol dammit!

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh man, finally found the issue lol.
The issue was a global the callbackID:

```
self.callbackId = command.callbackId;
```

Once I updated the code to pass the callbackId to the POST/GET everything started to work properly.

Posting here in case somebody else run into the issue:

Before:

```
- (void)http:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    self.callbackId  = command.callbackId;

    // NSURLSessionConfiguration
    [self initializeSession:headers];
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        [self doPost:url withData:data withHeaders:headers];
    } else {
        [self doGet:url withQueryString:queryString];
    }
}
```

After:

```
- (void)http:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    self.callbackId  = command.callbackId;

    // NSURLSessionConfiguration
    [self initializeSession:headers];
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
        [self doPost:url withData:data withHeaders:headers withCommandID:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        [self doGet:url withQueryString:queryString withCommandID:command.callbackId];
    }
}
```